# Trouble deploying to detected network (network/artifact mismatch)

Tags: solidity, truffle, metamask

I'm having some issues determining and connecting with the right MetaMask network.

In Ganache, my RPC server is 127.0.0.1.7545 and the network id is 5777. However, when I try to create a custom RPC in MetaMask with this info, I get the following error:

```
The endpoint returned a different chain ID: 1337
```

This is my truffle-config.js:

```
module.exports = {
  networks: {
    development: {
      host: "127.0.0.1",
      port: 7545,
      network_id: "*" // Match any network id
    },
    develop: {
      port: 8545
    }
  }
};
```

I'm hoping this would match to any network id as I've specified, but the console shows the following error:

```
Contract has not been deployed to detected network (network/artifact mismatch)
```

I've already tried truffle migrate --reset, without success. I've also tried creating an explicit network for testrpc in truffle-config.js - that didn't work either.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Did you specify --network development? Because the standard network for deploying with the "migrate" command is called "develop" (you can see it in your truffle-config.js, so you need to explicitly specify the network "development"

NOTE: you may also use the "truffle develop" command to get a truffle console and launch a local ganache blockchain. It helps me to fix troubles connecting truffle with ganache